# Dynamic Features not working on Iphones, Website created using Astro, and Preact

Tags: typescript, iphone, astrojs, preact

So I have a slider in my webpage, this slider set up using useState from preact/hooks. I have directly put up my Preact components in the .astro page.[image: code screenshot]

The problem is these interactive components work perfectly on all the devices but doesnt on Iphones. Not just this there are several interactive elements, in which changing the value of the input field, instantly changes the values dependent on it for some I have used useState, for some signal and useSignal. I have used astro's client directives to render it on the client side, so that these components arent static.

These doesnt work consistently, meaning it some components work sometimes but doesnt sometime. Most of the times it doesnt work at all. My best guess is since I have used client:load unless the component completely loads it doesnt work. But this doesnt happen in desktop or andriod phones. Its just for Iphones.

Also when I put everything in a .tsx component and then render this component to .astro page, it works perfectly. Why is this?
I dont want to do this since it ll greatly affect the page speed. Any Ideas on why this is happening just on Iphones?

Comment: Does it work on desktop Safari? Do you see any errors on the console when it doesn't work? The fact that it works if you put everything in one tsx file might indicate it's this Safari bug: https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/10055

Comment: It doesnt work on chrome as well in my mobile. I thougght it was because of the large amount of data I sent to component, so I reduced the redundant data, but it still not working.

Comment: on Chrome on iOS? if so, that doesn't count as on iOS all browsers currently just use Webkit (i.e. Safari) under the hood.